# How to disable the double click file renaming behavior on QTreeView and QFileSystemModel in PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt, double-click, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

Simple question. I'd like to use F2 or Enter for rename, and double click to open a file.

Using `self.treeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.doubleclick)` I can do things in my `self.doubleClick` method, but the renaming is still triggered.

The model is not read-only (`model.setReadOnly(False)`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the `doubleClicked` signal is emitted just before the normal editing action, which is carried out by the [QAbstractItemView.edit](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#edit-2) function.

Fortunately, this function is virtual, so it can be reimplemented in a subclass:

```
class TreeView(QtGui.QTreeView):    
    def edit(self, index, trigger, event):
        if trigger == QtGui.QAbstractItemView.DoubleClicked:
            print 'DoubleClick Killed!'
            return False
        return QtGui.QTreeView.edit(self, index, trigger, event)
```

Comment: Also note that you can press F2 to trigger renaming, so this doesn't handle that.

Comment: @GreenCell. The OP specifically asked to kill double-click editing, which is what the example code does. And it can easily be adapted to handle other kinds of editing (including F2 - or more precisely, the [platform edit-key](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractitemview.html#EditTrigger-enum)).

Comment: Yes I know, but F2 is a subtle thing that can easily be overlooked. Thought I mention it in case anyone wasn't thinking about it.

Comment: @GreenCell separate topic entirely, this is explicitly about DoubleClick. Easy to use `trigger == QAbstractItemView.EditKeyPressed` to achieve this for anyone wondering.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if you have this in python versions, but in C++ Qt you just set the edit triggers in the QAbstractItemView:

`void   setEditTriggers ( EditTriggers triggers )`

Comment: Just revisited this, and you're right: I completely overlooked `setEditTriggers`.

Comment: For examples of how to use this, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831242/qt-start-editing-of-cell-after-one-click/31197990#31197990